# Difference in color between image render and video render

Tags: rendering, color

Can anyone tell me why there is a subtle colour difference between my image render and video render?

[image: render]

This is an EXR image sequence that I have pre-rendered and am importing into the sequencer in a new project. The image render on the left has the correct colour, whereas when I render to video it comes out slightler darker and I can't figure out why.

My colour settings:

[image]

Comment: Hi :). The transfer from EXR (scene referred) to video codecs (display referred) isn't perfectly precise. You'll probably need to correct the colors in compositor ;)

Comment: What video codec do you use? If you use H.264, it has YUV Color space instead of sRGB, which can probably loss some colors during color convection.

Comment: I am using H.264. Should I be using something else?